# How to terminate a thread when main program ends?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

If I have a thread in an infinite loop, is there a way to terminate it when the main program ends (for example, when I press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**C**</kbd>)?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Check this question. The correct answer has great explanation on how to terminate threads the right way:
[Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

To make the thread stop on Keyboard Interrupt signal (ctrl+c) you can catch the exception "KeyboardInterrupt" and cleanup before exiting. Like this:

```
try:
    start_thread()  
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    cleanup_stop_thread()
    sys.exit()
```

This way you can control what to do whenever the program is abruptly terminated.

You can also use the built-in signal module that lets you setup signal handlers (in your specific case the SIGINT signal): http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I might have not stated the question correctly. In the example given in that question it was still necessary to execute the thread's stop() function. When I terminate a program abnormally by ctrl+C, that can't happen. So, my question is a bit like, "how do I call the mythread.stop() funcion if the main thread flow is interrupted"

Comment: Is `cleanup_stop_thread()` a global function that I can use? or should I need to implement it?

Comment: @alper, I think maybe it was just an example that is possible to implement something. You should implement that

Answer (score 132):

If you make your worker threads daemon threads, they will die when all your non-daemon threads (e.g. the main thread) have exited.

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon

Comment: Thanks for the simple and precise answer, the default threading.Thread daemon status `isDaemon()` is False, set it True by `setDaemon(True)`.

Comment: This answers the question and just works. The op did not ask how to exit threads cleanly in general.

Comment: `isDaemon()` and `setDaemon()` are old getters/setters (as per the linked doc above), just use `daemon=True` in `threading.Thread()`

Comment: Note that using daemon threads can cause other issues and is probably not what you want here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596918/python-exception-in-thread-thread-1-most-likely-raised-during-interpreter-shutd/20598791#20598791

Comment: To avoid using daemon threads and cleanly kill threads, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910372/script-stuck-on-exit-when-using-atexit-to-terminate-threads

Answer (score 34):

#### Try to enable the sub-thread as daemon-thread.

Recommended:

```
from threading import Thread

t = Thread(target=desired_method)
t.daemon = True  # Dies when main thread (only non-daemon thread) exits.
t.start()
```

Inline:

```
t = Thread(target=desired_method, daemon=True).start()
```

Old API:

```
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

---

When your main thread terminates (e.g. <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**C**</kbd> keystrokes), other threads will also be killed by the instructions above.

Comment: Note that using daemon threads can cause other issues and are probably not what you want here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596918/python-exception-in-thread-thread-1-most-likely-raised-during-interpreter-shutd/20598791#20598791

Answer (score 12):

Use the [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html?highlight=atexit#module-atexit) module of Python's standard library to register "termination" functions that get called (on the main thread) on any reasonably "clean" termination of the main thread, including an uncaught exception such as `KeyboardInterrupt`.  Such termination functions may (though inevitably in the main thread!) call any `stop` function you require; together with the possibility of setting a thread as `daemon`, that gives you the  tools to properly design the system functionality you need.

Comment: Note that this approach worked without requiring daemonized threads in Python versions prior to 2.6.5, see answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713360/python-2-6-x-theading-signals-atexit-fail-on-some-versions. This is unfortunate IMHO, since daemon threads during shutdown are a bit of a mess before python 3.4 (http://bugs.python.org/issue19466). If you stop _and_ join your daemon threads in your atexit handlers, all should be fine, at the (probably insignificant) cost of serializing your thread teardown.

Comment: Be aware that weird things can happen because of post-poned `atexit.register()` calls in Python modules, causing your termination procedure to be executed after the `multiprocessing`'s one. I run in this problem dealing with `Queue` and `daemon` threads: [“EOF error” at program exit using multiprocessing Queue and Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209385/eof-error-at-program-exit-using-multiprocessing-queue-and-thread/49244528#49244528).

Comment: Apparently in modern versions of Python, such as 3.7.4+, the `atexit` handlers aren't called when non-daemon threads are alive and the main thread exits. See [Script stuck on exit when using atexit to terminate threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910372/script-stuck-on-exit-when-using-atexit-to-terminate-threads).

Answer (score 9):

If you spawn a Thread like so - `myThread = Thread(target = function)` - and then do `myThread.start(); myThread.join()`. When CTRL-C is initiated, the main thread doesn't exit because it is waiting on that blocking `myThread.join()` call. To fix this, simply put in a timeout on the .join() call. The timeout can be as long as you wish. If you want it to wait indefinitely, just put in a really long timeout, like 99999. It's also good practice to do `myThread.daemon = True` so all the threads exit when the main thread(non-daemon) exits.

Comment: `myThread.daemon = True` is a wonderful solution to this problem.

Comment: @Brannon `.daemon=True` is in not a solid solution. Check this thread for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20598791/5562492

Answer (score 6):

Daemon threads are killed ungracefully so any finalizer instructions are not executed.
A possible solution is to check is main thread is alive instead of infinite loop.

E.g. for Python 3:

```
while threading.main_thread().isAlive():
    do.you.subthread.thing()
gracefully.close.the.thread()
```

See [Check if the Main Thread is still alive from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442651/check-if-the-main-thread-is-still-alive-from-another-thread).