# Script stuck on exit when using atexit to terminate threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, locking, python-multithreading, atexit

I'm playing around with threads on python 3.7.4, and I want to use `atexit` to register a cleanup function that will (cleanly) terminate the threads.

For example:

```
# example.py
import threading
import queue
import atexit
import sys

Terminate = object()

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

    def send_message(self, m):
        self.queue.put_nowait(m)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            m = self.queue.get()
            if m is Terminate:
                break
            else:
                print("Received message: ", m)


def shutdown_threads(threads):
    for t in threads:
        print(f"Terminating thread {t}")
        t.send_message(Terminate)
    for t in threads:
        print(f"Joining on thread {t}")
        t.join()
    else:
        print("All threads terminated")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = [
        Worker()
        for _ in range(5)
    ]
    atexit.register(shutdown_threads, threads)

    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.send_message("Hello")
        #t.send_message(Terminate)

    sys.exit(0)
```

However, it seems interacting with the threads and queues in the `atexit` callback creates a deadlock with some internal shutdown routine:

```
$ python example.py
Received message:  Hello
Received message:  Hello
Received message:  Hello
Received message:  Hello
Received message:  Hello
^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python3.7/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/threading.py", line 1308, in _shutdown
    lock.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
Terminating thread <Worker(Thread-1, started 140612492904192)>
Terminating thread <Worker(Thread-2, started 140612484511488)>
Terminating thread <Worker(Thread-3, started 140612476118784)>
Terminating thread <Worker(Thread-4, started 140612263212800)>
Terminating thread <Worker(Thread-5, started 140612254820096)>
Joining on thread <Worker(Thread-1, stopped 140612492904192)>
Joining on thread <Worker(Thread-2, stopped 140612484511488)>
Joining on thread <Worker(Thread-3, stopped 140612476118784)>
Joining on thread <Worker(Thread-4, stopped 140612263212800)>
Joining on thread <Worker(Thread-5, stopped 140612254820096)>
All threads terminated
```

(the `KeyboardInterrupt` is me using `ctrl-c` since the process seems to be hanging indefinitely).

However, if I send the `Terminate` message before exit(uncomment the line after `t.send_message("Hello")`), the program doesn't hang and terminates gracefully:

```
$ python example.py
Received message:  Hello
Received message:  Hello
Received message:  Hello
Received message:  Hello
Received message:  Hello
Terminating thread <Worker(Thread-1, stopped 140516051592960)>
Terminating thread <Worker(Thread-2, stopped 140516043200256)>
Terminating thread <Worker(Thread-3, stopped 140515961992960)>
Terminating thread <Worker(Thread-4, stopped 140515953600256)>
Terminating thread <Worker(Thread-5, stopped 140515945207552)>
Joining on thread <Worker(Thread-1, stopped 140516051592960)>
Joining on thread <Worker(Thread-2, stopped 140516043200256)>
Joining on thread <Worker(Thread-3, stopped 140515961992960)>
Joining on thread <Worker(Thread-4, stopped 140515953600256)>
Joining on thread <Worker(Thread-5, stopped 140515945207552)>
All threads terminated
```

This begs the question, when does this `threading._shutdown` routine gets executed, relative to `atexit` handlers?
Does it make sense to interact with threads in `atexit` handlers?

Comment: Why **don't** you want to do `#t.send_message(Terminate)`?

Comment: Apparently the interpreter doesn't call the `atexit` handlers until all the non-daemon threads have exited, which suspiciously sounds like a bug that was fixed in Python 2.6.5 (see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713360/python-2-6-x-theading-signals-atexit-fail-on-some-versions and https://bugs.python.org/issue1722344). A workaround might be to wrap the main code in `try` / `finally` and manually call `shutdown_threads(threads)` yourself.

Comment: Also see [How to terminate a thread when main program ends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564137/how-to-terminate-a-thread-when-main-program-ends)

Answer (score 10):

You can use one daemon thread to ask your non-daemon threads to clean up gracefully.  For an example where this is necessary, if you are using a third-party library that starts a non-daemon thread, you'd either have to change that library or do something like:

```
import threading

def monitor_thread():
    main_thread = threading.main_thread()
    main_thread.join()
    send_signal_to_non_daemon_thread_to_gracefully_shutdown()


monitor = threading.Thread(target=monitor_thread)
monitor.daemon = True
monitor.start()

start_non_daemon_thread()
```

To put this in the context of the original poster's code (note we don't need the atexit function, since that won't get called until all the non-daemon threads are stopped):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = [
        Worker()
        for _ in range(5)
    ]
    
    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.send_message("Hello")
        #t.send_message(Terminate)

    def monitor_thread():
        main_thread = threading.main_thread()
        main_thread.join()
        shutdown_threads(threads)

    monitor = threading.Thread(target=monitor_thread)
    monitor.daemon = True
    monitor.start()
```

Comment: This worked as expected for me but I noticed that it also works if `monitor_thread` is not a daemon thread. My explanation is that it already waits on `main_thread.join()` and therefore will wake up when `main_thread` exits.

The docs say "Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown.", which makes me think that here we actually may want `monitor` *not* be a daemon thread.

Comment: Here's a HUGE upvote and thank you. I've been struggling with this exact problem all day, where I want to start a quick thread (loading some data) upon django 4.2 startup. For some cryptic reason, I faced the exact same problem with the local development mode with autoreloader (using `sys.exit(3)` upon reloading), and skipping using `atexit` and signal handlers was the single best solution that worked.

Answer (score 1):

> **atexit.register(func)** registers `func` as a function to be executed at termination.

After execute the last line of code (it is `sys.exit(0)` in above example) in main thread, `threading._shutdown` was invoked (by interpreter) to wait for all non-daemon threads (Workers created in above example) exit

> The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.

So after typing **CTRL+C**, the main thread was terminated by `SIGINT` signal, and then **atexit** registered functions are called by interpreter.

By the way, if you pass `daemon=True` to `Thread.__init__`, the program would run straightforward without any human interactive.

Comment: Yes, but I want the threads to be killed gracefully, giving them a chance to execute cleanup code. That's what my atexit handler is supposed to be for.

Comment: As said above, you could achieve it via making the Worker a daemon thread (`super().__init__(daemon=True`).

Comment: It's my understanding that daemon threads are not given a chance to handle their termination gracefully, e.g. cleanup any resources they might be holding on. They are simply killed brutally when the main thread exits, and are not considered at all during the runtime shutdown process. See this for potential issues with using them, for example: https://www.joeshaw.org/python-daemon-threads-considered-harmful/

Comment: `atexit` is an exception to allow us do some cleanup actions before Python interpreter do real finalization. > The interpreter is still entirely intact at this point (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pylifecycle.c#L1276)

Comment: As a prove, you could add a logging after Worker got a `Terminate` from queue. You would see that the Workers are still alive during the execution of `atexit` registered functions.

Comment: Ok, I see, that make sense. Either I use daemon threads and atexit, or I have to do shutdown "manually" before exit. Thanks!