# "EOF error" at program exit using multiprocessing Queue and Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing

I have trouble understanding why this simple program raises an [`EOFError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#EOFError) at the end.

I am using a [`Queue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) to communicate with a [`Thread()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) that I want to automatically and cleanly terminate [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#atexit.register) of my program.

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
import atexit

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = None
        self.thread = None

    def start(self):
        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.queued_writer, daemon=True)
        self.thread.start()

        # Remove this: no error
        self.queue.put("message")

    def queued_writer(self):
        while 1:
            msg = self.queue.get()
            print("Message:", msg)
            if msg is None:
                break

    def stop(self):
        self.queue.put(None)
        self.thread.join()

instance = MyClass()

atexit.register(instance.stop)

# Put this before register: no error
instance.start()
```

This raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 21, in queued_writer
    msg = self.queue.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 94, in get
    res = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Moreover, this snippet behaves strangely: if I remove the `self.queue.put("message")` line, no error is raised and the thread exits successfully. Similarly, this seems to work if the `instance.start()` is call before `atexit.register()`.

Does anyone know from where could come the error please?

**Edit:** I noticed that using a [`SimpleQueue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.SimpleQueue) seems to make the error disappear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue comes from a conflict between multiple [`atexit.register()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/atexit.html#atexit.register) calls.

The documentation states that:

> `atexit` runs these functions in the reverse order in which they were registered; if you register `A`, `B`, and `C`, at interpreter termination time they will be run in the order `C`, `B`, `A`.
>
> [...]
>
> The assumption is that lower level modules will normally be imported before higher level modules and thus must be cleaned up later.

By first importing `multiprocessing` and then calling `atexit.register(my_stop)`, you would expect your stop function to be executed before any internal termination procedure... But this is not the case, because `atexit.register()` may be called dynamically.

In the present case, the `multiprocessing` library makes use of a [`_exit_function`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e2732d3e66eba9ec13f9d55c499f2437ead552db/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#L285) function which is meant to cleanly close internal threads and queues. This function is registered in `atexit` [at the module level](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e2732d3e66eba9ec13f9d55c499f2437ead552db/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#L327), however the module is only loaded [once the `Queue()` object is initialized](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e2732d3e66eba9ec13f9d55c499f2437ead552db/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py#L101).

Consequently, the `MyClass` stop function is registered **before** the `multiprocessing`'s one and thus `instance.stop` is called **after** `_exit_function`.

During its termination, `_exit_function` closes internal pipes connections, so if the thread later try to call `.get()` with a closed read-connection, an `EOFError` is raised. This happens only if Python did not have time to automatically kill the `daemon` thread at the end, that is if a "slow" exit function (like `time.sleep(0.1)` or in this case `thread.join()`) is register and run after the usual closure procedure. For some reason, the write-connection shutdown is delayed hence `.put()` does not raise error immediately.

As to why small modifications to the snippet makes it work: `SimpleQueue` does not have `Finalizer` so internal pipe is closed later. The internal thread of `Queue` is not started until the first `.put()` is called so removing it means there is no pipe to close. It is also posible to force registeration by importing `multiprocessing.queues`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it you can define `__enter__` and `__exit__` inside your class and create your instance using `with` statement:

```
import threading
import multiprocessing


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = None
        self.thread = None

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.stop()

    def start(self):
        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.queued_writer, daemon=True)
        self.thread.start()

    def queued_writer(self):
        while 1:
            msg = self.queue.get()
            print("Message:", str(msg))
            if msg is None:
                break

    def put(self, msg):
        self.queue.put(msg)

    def stop(self):
        self.queue.put(None)
        self.thread.join()


with MyClass() as instance:
    instance.start()
    print('Thread stopped: ' + str(instance.thread._is_stopped))
    instance.put('abc')

print('Thread stopped: ' + str(instance.thread._is_stopped))
```

Above code gives as an output:

```
Thread stopped: False
Message: abc
Message: None
Thread stopped: True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I am not specifically asking about workaround, I would rather like to know **why** my snippet is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The surface answer to your question is fairly simple, The queued_writer process is still waiting for entries to be written to the queue when the main process ends, sending an EOF to the open blocking connection that `self.queue.get` opened.

That raises the question of why the `atexit.register` didn't seem to do it's job, but of that I do not know the reason for.