# Python kill every single thread, the main python process, etc

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, kill, kill-process

Yes I know that it's not a good idea to do this and there are more "graceful" ways. But I still want to have a button that kills every single process alive.

I tried `sys.exit()` but for some reason that did not close all the threads. (why?)

And I do **NOT** want to use flags,stop(), etc.

Is this posiible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-terminate-a-thread-when-main-program-ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564137)