# Python uncaught exceptions in main not killing threads

Tags: python, multithreading, exception

When I run a python program (2.7 or 3), I import a module that has a class that initializes some threads. The problem is whenever an **uncaught exception** occurs in the main thread, the main function dies yet the thread keeps running like a zombie causing the python process to never die.

What's the best way to have any uncaught exception in the main thread (or even other threads) to kill everything everywhere.

Since I often call the `subprocess` module, I usually use `threading.Event` to help exit cleanly. However, uncaught exceptions won't trigger those events.

Here's an example of a program where the thread just won't die....

prog1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import threading
import modx1

mod_obj = modx1.Moddy()

raise Exception('DIE UNEXPECTEDLY')

try:
    raise Exception('known problem here')
except Exception:
    mod_obj.kill_event.set()
```

modx1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import threading
import subprocess
from time import sleep


class Moddy():
    def __init__(self):
        self.kill_event = threading.Event()
        self.my_thread=threading.Thread(target=self.thread_func)
        self.my_thread.start()
    def thread_func(self):
        while  not self.kill_event.is_set():
            print('thread still going....')
            sleep(2)
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564137/how-to-terminate-a-thread-when-main-program-ends  Maybe the daemon flag is what you want?

Comment: I looked at that. I don't need a generic idea of daemon threads and/or using events. My specific concerns are not addressed directly in that post. Although the code itself doesn't show it, I can't use daemon threads because of all the spawned processes in a lot of my code.<br>
For the answer that I accepted here, I did see the solution ("threading.main_thread().is_alive()") in an unaccepted answer at the bottom of that post. But, again, this post is not a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be hackish, but still something to start with.

**prog1.py** - I have added sleep of 5 seconds so you can see the thread running and then gets completed.

```
import modx1
import time


mod_obj = modx1.Moddy()
time.sleep(5)
raise Exception('DIE UNEXPECTEDLY')

try:
    raise Exception('known problem here')
except Exception:
    mod_obj.kill_event.set()
```

**modx1.py** -> Check for the boolean you set and also the status of main thread.

```
import ctypes
import threading
import subprocess
from time import sleep


class Moddy():
    def __init__(self):
        self.kill_event = threading.Event()
        self.my_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_func)
        self.my_thread.start()

    def thread_func(self):
        while not self.kill_event.is_set() and threading.main_thread().is_alive():
            print('thread still going....')
            sleep(2)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
thread still going....
thread still going....
thread still going....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gaurishankarbadola/PycharmProjects/untitled1/prog1.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise Exception('DIE UNEXPECTEDLY')
Exception: DIE UNEXPECTEDLY

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: threading.main_thread.is_alive() !! I didn't know that was a thing!
Thank you! This is what I needed!

Comment: Considering that i use threading Events to shut everything down cleanly, I'm starting to think ```threading.main_thread().is_alive()``` could easily stand in to replace any such events...

Comment: @MookiBar yes, that could be a possibility, but sometimes your main thread might be running and you still want to kill the child thread and in that scenario, your `self.kill_event.is_set()` logic is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not reliant on clean up occurring in the threads, the simplest solution is to just launch all your threads as daemon threads; a Python program exits when all non-daemon threads have completed, so if your main thread is the only non-daemon thread, the program will terminate when the main thread does.

The change required is trival, just change:

```
self.my_thread=threading.Thread(target=self.thread_func)
```

to:

```
self.my_thread=threading.Thread(target=self.thread_func, daemon=True)
```

and the thread will be launched as a daemon.

If you do have cleanup that must occur and isn't automatic on program termination (e.g. sending some "I'm done" message to a remote machine over the network, where simply closing the connection isn't sufficient for whatever reason), `daemon` won't work (the threads are forcibly terminated, whatever they were in the middle of), so you can use your approach, you just need to expand the `try` block to cover all code from the moment the thread is launched so the handling always occurs. I'd also recommend `set`-ing the `Event` in a `finally` block, not an `except` block, if you want to always tell the threads to clean up, not just when something bad happens. If it should be done only on an exception, I'd use a bare `except:` block, and explicitly re-`raise` after setting `Event`, e.g.:

```
try:
    # Entire program after thread launches
except:
    mod_obj.kill_event.set()
    raise  # Reraises exception as if it were never caught, rather than silencing it
```

Comment: hey, just as my comment was written.  good to know it's applicable, my threading-fu is sadly lacking.

Comment: Unfortunately, daemon threads aren't ideal. Like i said, i use 'subprocess' a lot, and daemon threads would kill them in an unclean way (zombie processes).

Comment: Also unfortunate that the latter half means I'd have to put the entire code into a try/except block.
Is there not something similar to a flag or signal that can do the trick?

Comment: @MookiBar: You could put a handler in [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) to do the same job. The flaw is that it's a single, global handler, and some third-party libraries might rely on it as well, causing conflicts if all overriders aren't careful to preserve the hook they replaced and call it when they're done. It's not *that* hard to put all the code in the `try` block though. If you hate extra indentation, put the code that would be in the `try` block in another function, and make the contents of the `try` block a call to that function.

Comment: Good point. I tend to put everything after the obligatory ```if __name__ == "__main__"``` into a seperate function, so it wouldn't be the worst thing in the world. I've just had others look down on me for ```try/except```ing my whole code...